# Integrating plas.io pointcloud viewer into my own web app

Tags: point-clouds, plas.io

I am experimenting with plas.io to display pointclouds in LAS format. This is a brilliantly good piece of work using WebGL.

I want to integrate plas.io into an existing node app. It would be best to have the display (of the model, not the controls) built right into my current UI. The LAS file in question comes from S3. Are there hooks/APIs which I can use to accomplish such a thing?

It would also be acceptable to have plas.io running in a iframe in my app. I would run a separate plas.io server. However, I would like the iframe to display only the model again, not the controls, and pass in both the file to be rendered and the parameters to render it somehow, perhaps as query parameters to a URL handed off to plas.io.

I have posted this question to the Issues section of plas.io's github page, but no response. Any ideas about how I should proceed here?

Comment: Any success so far?I am also looking to achieve same.